# WinHttpSendRequest returns 12044 ERROR_WINHTTP_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED

Tags: certificate, client, winhttp

since 3 years I acces the ebay api from WinHttp. Since today I get error 12044, ERROR_WINHTTP_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED, after calling WinHttpSendRequest. May I use whatever SSL certificate and load it from the store? Getting one from letsencrypt.org, install it and load it by CertFindCertificateInStore and enable it with WinHttpSetOption? How ebay know that this certificate is connected to my credentials like appid, certid and runame?

I have no idea what to do, sorry for that question.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Created a self-signed certificate, add it to store, exported a private key, granted access to this private key and load the key after creating the request.

WinHttpOpenRequest...
CertOpenStore...
CertFindCertificateInStore...
WinHttpSetOption...
CertFreeCertificateContext...
CertCloseStore...
WinHttpSendRequest...

In fact, added the lines from CertOpenStore to CertCloseStore. Nothing else changed and it works.